# Drupal | Paragraph | How to modify field in paragraph for just one node

Tags: php, drupal

Modify paragraph_field just for one node

I have issue use paragraph module.I want modify paragraph_field just for one node. Many node of mine use one paragraph but I must modify by write over paragraph--item--default.html.twig. But by this way many node of mine can be change when modify paragraph--paragraph-item--.html.twig.
If no solve for above issue I want to ask how to target field like example {{content.field_item[0].field_image[0]}}
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly should be modified? The behaviour of the field or the style of the field? Or should the field not be visible when adding the paragraph to the node?